# How to dynamically update layouts in android studio

Tags: android, user-interface, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a mobile application in android studio with Java. I am working with a Firebase realtime database, and in the database exists a list of "tasks" each with a name and description.

What I would like to happen is for my application to dynamically render a list of cards representing each task based on how many tasks are in the database. I also have a button that allows users to add a task, and after adding the task I would like another card to be rendered with the added task data.

I understand this to be a very routine task, and it is something I am very familiar with doing in web development. I am unsure of how to do this in android studio, as the UI is defined in a layout XML file, and I am unsure of how to dynamically change the layout XML file based on how much data is fetched from the database.

If anyone can provide any help or helpful links to how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that you might be interested in reading this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView to populate views dynamically. RecyclerView is the most efficient and optimized.

Useful resources:

- [RecyclerView official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=CjwKCAiAtdGNBhAmEiwAWxGcUvi36PNMa6biDIsRrYztcGINTxbH4Z1IcUvb1AbvK5LJNzKTg3PunxoCcQQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)
- [Using Firebase with RecyclerView Full guide video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub6mNHWGVHw&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBf5KH4XXOthtgo6E4Epjl8&index=28)